# Host command and web browser's don't accept hosts.conf order

Tags: linux, dns, fedora

```
[root@MYPC etc]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
Release:    14
Codename:   Laughlin

[root@MYPC etc]# uname -a
Linux MYPC 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.i686.PAE #1 SMP Mon Feb 7 06:57:55 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

[root@MYPC etc]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8

[root@MYPC etc]# cat /etc/host.conf 
multi on
order hosts,bind

[root@MYPC etc]# cat /etc/hosts
192.168.1.2 MYPC    # Added by NetworkManager
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1 MYPC    localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

127.0.0.0   audit.median.hu

[root@MYPC etc]# ping audit.median.hu
Do you want to ping broadcast? Then -b

[root@MYPC etc]# host -t a audit.median.hu
audit.median.hu has address 193.68.35.149
audit.median.hu has address 193.91.69.232
audit.median.hu has address 193.68.35.131
audit.median.hu has address 193.68.35.136
```

Why does `ping` see `audit.median.hu` as 127.0.0.0, and why does `host -t a audit.median.hu` see it as 193.68.35.149? `audit.median.hu` is just an example site [hosts ads, etc.]

I just have a caching nameserver on my Fedora PC:

```
yum -y install caching-nameserver
service named restart
chkconfig named on
```

I configured my DNS server addresses in the Network-Manager Applet: 127.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8

Even with Wireshark, I can see it:

```
`195.70.37.149 DNS Standard query A audit.median.hu`
```

So the big question: Why don't the `host` command or my web browser recognize that I have modified `audit.median.hu`s IP address?

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` do you have

```
hosts:      files dns
```

set?

Comment: http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1125975

Comment: Might be being silly but I'm not sure whether host actually abides by nsswitch.conf... could you try using 'ping' or closing/reopening the browser and trying again?

Comment: After running strace on __host__ on my Ubuntu 10.10 box I can see no reference to either /etc/host.conf, /etc/nsswitch.conf or libnss.  My guess is it doesn't use them.  (I could delve into the source code if you like).

Comment: what about ping/your browser after restarting?